# Можете ли Вы пересказать "сюжет" ахмадулинского стихотворения, наполненного архаизмами и церковнославянизмами?

Tags: значение-слов, литература, смысл, архаизмы, славянизмы

> Хожу по околицам дюжей весны,
>
> вкруг полой воды, и сопутствие чье-то
>
> глаголаше: «Колицем должен еси?» —
>
> сочти, как умеешь, я сбилась со счёта.
>
> ---
>
> Хотелось мне моря, Батума, дождя,
>
> кофейни и фески Омара-соседа.
>
> Бубнило уже: «Ты должна, ты должна!» —
>
> и двинулась я не овамо, а семо.
>
> ---
>
> Прибой возыметь за спиной, на восток,
>
> вершины ожегший, воззриться – могла ведь.
>
> Всевластье трубы помавает хвостом,
>
> предместье-прихвостье корпит, помогает.
>
> ---
>
> Закат – и скорбит и робеет душа
>
> пред пурпуром смрадным, прекрасно-зловещим.
>
> Над гранью земли – ты должна, ты должна! —
>
> на злате небес – филигрань-человечек.
>
> ---
>
> Его пожирает отверстый вулкан,
>
> его не спасет тихомолка оврага,
>
> идет он – и поздно его окликать —
>
> вдоль пламени, в челюсти антропофага.
>
> ---
>
> Сближаются алое и фиолет.
>
> Как стебель в средине захлопнутой книги,
>
> меж ними расплющен его силуэт —
>
> лишь вмятина видима в стынущем нимбе.
>
> ---
>
> Добыча побоища и дележа —
>
> невзрачная крапина крови и воли.
>
> Как скушно жужжит: «Ты должна, ты должна!» —
>
> тому ли скитальцу? Но нет его боле.
>
> ---
>
> Я в местной луне, поначалу, своей
>
> луны не узнала, да сжалилась лунность
>
> и свойски зависла меж черных ветвей —
>
> так ей приглянулась столь смелая глупость.
>
> ---
>
> Меж тем я осталась одна, как она:
>
> лишь нищие звери тянулись во други
>
> да звук допекал: «Ты должна, ты должна!» —
>
> ужель оборучью хапуги-округи?
>
> ---
>
> Ее постояльцы забыли мотив,
>
> родимая речь им далече латыни,
>
> снуют, ненасытной мечтой охватив
>
> кто – реки хмельные, кто – горы златые.
>
> ---
>
> Не ласки и взоры, а лязг и возня.
>
> Пришла для подачи – осталась при плаче.
>
> Их скаредный скрытень скрадет и меня.
>
> Незнаемый молвил: «Тем паче, тем паче».
>
> ---
>
> Текут добры молодцы вотчины вспять.
>
> Трущобы трещат – и пусты деревеньки.
>
> Пошто бы им загодя джинсы не дать?
>
> По сей промтовар все идут в делинквенты.
>
> ---
>
> Восход малолетства задирчив и быстр:
>
> тетрадки да прятки, а больше – рогатки.
>
> До зверских убийств от звериных убийств
>
> по прямопутку шагают ребятки.
>
> ---
>
> Заради наживы решат на ножах:
>
> не пусто ли брату остаться без брата?
>
> Пребудут не живы – мне будет не жаль.
>
> Истец улыбнулся: «Неправда, неправда».
>
> ---
>
> Да ты их не видывал! Кто ты ни есть,
>
> они в твою высь не взглянули ни разу.
>
> И крестят детей, полагая, что крест —
>
> условье улова и средство от сглазу.
>
> ---
>
> До станции и до кладбища дошла,
>
> чей вид и названье содеяны сажей.
>
> Опять донеслось: «Ты должна, ты должна!» —
>
> я думала, что-нибудь новое скажет.
>
> ---
>
> Забытость надгробья нежна и прочна.
>
> О, лакомка, сразу доставшийся раю!
>
> «Вкушая, вкусих мало мёду, – прочла,
>
> уже не прочесть: – и се аз умираю».
>
> ---
>
> Заведомый ангел, жилец неземной,
>
> как прочие все оснащенный скелетом.
>
> «Ночной – на дневной, а шестой – на седьмой!» —
>
> вдруг рявкнул вблизи станционный селектор.
>
> ---
>
> Я стала любить эти вскрики ничьи,
>
> пророчества малых событий и ругань.
>
> Утешно мне их соучастье в ночи,
>
> когда сортируют иль так, озоруют.
>
> ---
>
> Гигант-репетир ударяет впотьмах,
>
> железо наслав на другое железо:
>
> вагону, под горку, препона – «башмак» —
>
> и сыплется снег с потрясенного леса.
>
> ---
>
> Твердящий темно: «Ты должна, ты должна!» —
>
> учись направлять, чтобы слышащий понял,
>
> и некий ночной, грохоча и дрожа,
>
> воспомнил свой долг и веленье исполнил.
>
> ---
>
> Незрячая ощупь ума не точна:
>
> лелея во мгле коридора-ущелья,
>
> не дали дитяти дьячка для тычка,
>
> для лестовицей ременной наущенья.
>
> ---
>
> Откройся: кто ты? Ослабел и уснул
>
> злохмурый, как мурин, посёлок немытый.
>
> Суфлёр в занебесном укрытье шепнул:
>
> «Ты знаешь его, он – неправедный мытарь.
>
> ---
>
> Призвал он кого́ждо из должников,
>
> и мало взыскал, и хвалим был от Бога».
>
> Но, буде ты – тот, почему не таков
>
> и не отпустишь от мзды и побора?
>
> ---
>
> Окраина эта тошна и душна! —
>
> Брезгливо изрёк сортировочный рупор:
>
> «Зла суща – ступай, ибо ты не должна
>
> ни нам, ни местам нашим гиблым и грубым.
>
> ---
>
> Таков уж твой сорт». – И подавленный всхлип
>
> превысил слова про пути и про рейсы.
>
> Потом я узнала: там сцепщик погиб.
>
> Сам голову положил он на рельсы.
>
> ---
>
> Не он ли вчера, напоследок дыша,
>
> вдоль неба спешил из огня да в полымя?
>
> И слабый пунктир – ты должна, ты должна! —
>
> насквозь пролегал между нами двоими.
>
> ---
>
> Хожу к тете Тасе, сижу и гляжу
>
> на розан бумажный в зеленом вазоне.
>
> Всю ночь потолок над глазами держу,
>
> понять не умею и каюсь во злобе.
>
> ---
>
> Иду в Афанасово крепким ледком,
>
> по талой воде возвращаюсь оттуда.
>
> И по пути, усмехнувшись тайком,
>
> куплю мандариновый джем из Батума.
>
> ---
>
> Покинувший – снова пришел: «Ты должна
>
> заснуть, возомненья приидут иные».
>
> Заснежило, и снизошла тишина,
>
> и молвлю во сне: отпущаеши ныне…

*Иваново, март 1986*

---

Редактирую - по непонятному мне требованию привести вопрос в соответствие с тематикой сайта. Вот про сватью бабу бабариху спрашивать можно, приветствуется, а про филигрань-человечка - ни-ни!

Многие слова и образы из гениального стихотворения, НАПИСАННОГО НА РУССКОМ ЯЗЫКЕ, остались для меня спорнотолкуемыми, например:

---

Кроме Белки и Селектора, кто - действующие лица? Истец, Суфлёр, Филигрань-Человечек? Ещё?..

Нет, а как они славно с Селектором пообщались: Белка только думает, а он, как в фильме-кошмаре "Прикосновение", вещает вслух:

*«Зла суща – ступай, ибо ты не должна*

*ни нам, ни местам нашим гиблым и грубым».*

А филигрань-человечек - опережающая проекция погибшего сцепщика?
И что делает строфа (вместе с содержимым)

*Незрячая ощупь ума не точна:*

*лелея во мгле коридора-ущелья,*

*не дали дитяти дьячка для тычка,*

*для лестовицей ременной наущенья* -

меж предыдущей и последующей? почему она (Белка) хлопочет о "некоем ночном" - это ему предстоит стать орудием казни сцепщика? который и есть филигрань-человечек, которого силуэт расплющили в средине захлопнутой книги? которому не дали "дьячка для тычка", а лелеяли на стыке алого и фиолета?

Comment: Долго отвечать - целый анализ получится, почти исследовательская работа. Вот ссылочка на реферат, здесь есть кое-что.http://www.newreferat.com/ref-6018-15.html3.

Comment: Люся, спасибо, зачем мне реферат? К тому же я в него заглядывала (и с тоской захлопнула) - много лет назад, когда не могла найти текст. Я сама что хошь напишу, но - лирическое, ненаучное, на что нет спроса... Сейчас же я прошу просто, "своими словами", пересказать, что происходит, назвать действующих лиц. И какой меж ими конфликт.

Comment: Сюжет: лирическая героиня постоянно ходит добывать продукты. Денег элементарно не хватает. Она наодалживала столько, что и не помнит уже, сколько и кому. Всё покрылось тайной, мраком, подозрением, что долги не вернуть. А хочется ещё кофе и джинсы ))

Comment: Юмор оценён, но дурачок ты маленький! ))) В делинквенты пошёл восход малолетства - по причине в стране с бумагой напряжёнка. Ну приди, построфно расскажи в ответе!

Comment: Один секунд, Галина, дам ещё голос на переоткрытие. А вопрос я заценила уже (почти сразу же, полгода назад).  Ответ Людмилы хорош, впрочем, — как всегда.

Comment: Спасибо, Риммочка! Такой ответ, как Люсин, дорогого стоит. Здесь уже делали пару попыток пересказа, потом в ужасе от содеянного кошмара сами же и удаляли. Удивительно всё было мимо, только Люся *пьет текст*, как я.

Comment: На данный момент это по-прежнему вопрос за границами языкознания. Поверьте, мне совсем неохота закрывать вопросы о литературе, тем более хорошие. Но правила есть правила, сайт — о русском языке, а не о русской литературе и пересказах. (Тем не менее, правила никогда не поздно менять и я думаю, что расширение тематики сайта до русской литературы может оказаться полезным. Welcome to Meta! https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Аэр, будь человеком, открой вопрос! Он именно о русском языке в различных его изводах-излётах. Ответ Людмилы - бесценная драгоценность! Могу изменить шапку вопроса, включив в него первую строку стихотворения - тогда инетный люд валом сюда повалит: стихи-то трудночитаемые, у исследователей творчества Ахмадулиной вызывают серию вопросов по толкованию...

Comment: Ваш вопрос был переоткрыт, хотя это не по правилам. Пример демократической воли )) (Я-то не против, но и правила тогда изменить надо.) Прошу вас отмечать меня как @Aer, иначе мне не приходят уведомления.

Comment: «Мы приветствуем вопросы, связанные с различными разделами языкознания (будь то орфография или пунктуация, синтаксис или грамматика, этимология или лексика), о его истории и современном состоянии» — ни слова про литературоведение.

Comment: @Aer, во-первых спасибо и земной поклон, мы вот с Люсей всё новые спорные места находим, но это не литературоведение: усложнённая лексика мешает нам пробраться к смыслу; а "во-вторых" вытекает из "во-первых": это всё-таки «об истории языка и современном его состоянии».

Comment: Может, и на стыке, но никак не чисто языковедческий: пересказывать содержание и толковать, кому же все-таки придется "стать орудием казни сцепщика", — дела филологов, не лингвистов. Если бы у нас был филологический сайт — пожалуйста, но ведь реальность иная, не правда ли?

Comment: @Aer! Филолог =  лингвист!  )))

Comment: Не будем начинать этот несколько пустой спор, но далеко не каждый филолог лингвист (и наоборот). Лингвистика и филология две разные науки, первая из которых «оторвалась от ветки родимой» уже в XIX веке (если не раньше). Не зря наш сайт лингвистический, а не филологический!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пожалуй, попробую. Стихотворение написано в конце 80-х, когда Б. А. увлекалась экзистенциализмом. Её архаика в стиле -  бегство от современности, обыденности, способ создания идеального микрокосмоса, который Ахмадулина наделяла своими ценностями и смыслами.

Общий смысл: героиня ходит в рабочем пригороде, голос свыше взывает к чувству долга и напоминает о вечных нравственных ценностях, которые забыты в современном городе.

Хожу по околицам полновластной (дюжей) весны,

обходя разливы полой воды, и кто-то невидимый (сопутствие чье-то)

спрашивает: "Сколько ты должен?" («Колицем должен еси?»). Она отвечает:
 — сочти, как умеешь, я сбилась со счёта. (Это реминисценция из Библии о мытаре - сборщике налогов, который простил людям долги. **Напоминает о высоких целях и желаниях).**

Героине хотелось простых человеческих радостей, любви.

(Хотелось мне моря, Батума, дождя,кофейни и фески Омара-соседа - это воспоминания о Грузии, где она отдыхала с Евтушенко, своей первой любовью).

Но сверху раздалось: «Ты должна, ты должна!» —

и она пошла не в сторону моря, а прочь от него, от солнца - не туда, а сюда, в рабочий пригород.

(...двинулась я не овамо, а семо. Прибой возыметь за спиной, на восток, вершины ожегший, воззриться – могла ведь.)

А там - всевластье трубы помавает хвостом, т. е. заводская  труба манит, машет своим дымом, как хвостом. Это пригород работает (предместье-прихвостье корпит, помогает).

Вечером, на закате страшно смотреть на зловещий дым из трубы. Сверху кто-то напоминает о высших ценностях, а здесь видение: труба и пламя из неё пожирают облака в форме человечка, даже небо жёлтое, человечек идёт прямо в пасть людоеда (антропофага). Смешиваются алый цвет и фиолетовый - ассоциации с дымом из литейки.

Человечек исчез,осталась лишь невзрачная крапина крови и воли.

Добыча побоища и дележа — реминисценции из библейских историй: когда человек умирает, его душу делят светлые и тёмные силы.

И непонятно, кому говорит видение: «Ты должна, ты должна!» —

тому ли скитальцу? Но нет его боле.

Даже луна была не так романтична, как всегда, она  зависла меж черных ветвей —

так ей приглянулась столь смелая глупость.

Героиня осталась одна, как одинокая луна.

Лишь нищие звери тянулись в друзья

да звук допекал: «Ты должна, ты должна!»

Только вот кому? Неужели оборучью хапуги-округи? Хапуга-округа - символ мещанского окружения, которое забыло красоту музыки, родной язык, их мечты пошлы и низки - пьянство, богатство, вместо любви -  лязг и возня.

Пришла с высокими радостными мыслями (для подачи) – осталась  плачущей, боясь, что пошлость поглотит и её (Их скаредный скрытень скрадет и меня - монстр в виде сундука с вещами).

Незнаемый молвил: "Тем более, тем более" («Тем паче, тем паче»), напоминая, что её долг устоять и на других повлиять.

Уходит молодёжь из родной стороны, из пригородов и деревень.

Почему бы им сразу не дать джинсы? (Намёк на то, что из-за них в 80-е молодёжь шла на всё, даже на преступление - спекуляцию, контрабанду, покупку валюты.)

Из-за них все идут в делинквенты - правонарушители.

Дети растут быстро: сначала школа и игры в прятки, потом рогатки.

Сначала убивают кошек и собак, потом людей - прямой путь в тюрьму. Из-за наживы убьют и брата. Их не жаль.

Истец (тот, кто спрашивал о долгах) улыбнулся: «Неправда, неправда».

Героиня  противоречит: - Да ты их не видывал! Кто ты ни есть,

они в твою высь не взглянули ни разу.

И крестят детей, полагая, что крест —

условье улова и средство от сглазу. Т. е. они даже детей крестят, чтобы извлечь выгоду.

До станции и до кладбища дошла,

чей вид и названье содеяны сажей.

Опять донеслось: «Ты должна, ты должна!» —

я думала, что-нибудь новое скажет.

Посмотрела - здесь покоится кто-то праведный (О, лакомка, сразу доставшийся раю!)

Первую часть надписи прочитала: «Вкушая, вкусих мало мёду, вторую уже не прочесть, её вспомнила: – и се аз умираю», - реминисценция из Библии и М. Ю. Лермонтова, который взял цитату  в качестве эпиграфа к поэме «Мцыри»: жил мало, мало видел радости, и вот теперь умираю.

Заведомый ангел, жилец неземной,

как прочие все оснащенный скелетом, - так как умер рано, не успел нагрешить.

«Ночной – на дневной, а шестой – на седьмой!» —

вдруг рявкнул вблизи станционный селектор.

Героиня привыкла к этим крикам как к пророчествам малых событий, даже к  ругани.

Ей нравится, что по селектору говорит тот, кто показывает своё  соучастье в ночи, когда сортируют иль так, озоруют.

Механизм для перевода стрелок (гигант-репетир) ударяет впотьмах,

железо наслав на другое железо:

вагону, под горку, препона – «башмак» —

и сыплется снег с потрясенного леса.

Голос в темноте твердит: «Ты должна, ты должна!» напоминает, что нужно учиться направлять других, как этот селектор, чтобы слышащий понял,

и некий ночной поезд, грохоча и дрожа,

воспомнил свой долг и веленье исполнил.

Самому ему трудно найти путь  во мгле коридора-ущелья,

направляющий голос важен, как для дитяти важен дьячок-наставник, наказывающий его ремнём.

Откройся: кто ты? Ослабел и уснул

злохмурый, как чернокожий эфиоп, посёлок немытый.

Голос с неба шепнул:

«Ты знаешь его, он – неправедный мытарь.

Призвал он каждого (кого́ждо) из должников,

и мало взыскал, и хвалим был от Бога», - реминисценция из Библии.

Но, буде ты – тот, почему не таков

и не отпустишь от мзды и побора?

Окраина эта тошна и душна! —

Брезгливо изрёк сортировочный рупор:

«Зла суща – ступай, ибо ты не должна

ни нам, ни местам нашим гиблым и грубым.

Таков уж твой сорт». – И подавленный всхлип

скрыл (превысил) слова про пути и про рейсы.

Потом она узнала: там сцепщик погиб.

Сам голову положил он на рельсы.

Она подумала, не его ли видела вчера на горизонте, когда он

вдоль неба спешил из огня да в полымя? Не его ли приняла за облако-человечка, съеденного трубой-людоедом? Может, это ему она задолжала?

(И слабый пунктир – ты должна, ты должна! —

насквозь пролегал между нами двоими).

Она идёт к тете Тасе, сидит и глядит на розан бумажный в зеленом вазоне - символ мещанства, смотрит в потолок, пытается понять, кается во злобе.

Идёт в Афанасово по  крепкому ледку, возвращается по талой воде. По пути, усмехнувшись тайком, покупает мандариновый джем - хоть что-то от своей мечты о Батуме.

Виденье снова пришло: «Ты должна

заснуть, возомненья приидут иные».

Заснула, и стало тихо, и произносит во сне: отпущаеши ныне… - начало молитвы: "Сейчас отпускаешь раба Твоего, Владыка, по слову Твоему, с миром, потому что видели очи мои спасение Твоё, которое Ты приготовил перед лицом всех народов, свет к просвещению язычников и славу народа Твоего Израиля", - реминисценция из Библии. Песнь Симеона Богоприимца — слова из Евангелия от Луки (Лк 2:29-32), произнесенные Симеоном Богоприимцем в Иерусалимском Храме в день Сретения — встречи старца с младенцем Иисусом Христом. Песнь вошла в состав богослужебных песнопений — это древнейший христианский гимн. Он читается или поется в конце вечерни, перед утреней, что символично: чинопоследование вечерни отражает ветхозаветную историю, а она, по сути, завершается старцем Симеоном, взявшим на руки Спасителя.

Т. е. заканчивается всё видение победой христианских ценностей. Смысл: на кого бы ты ни был зол - отпусти его с миром, жить нужно, понимая всех и помня о долге перед Богом и людьми, о высоких целях.

Ну вот как-то так.

Comment: Люсенька, огромное Вам спасибо - бесценный ответ! Меня заставили редактировать вопрос по причине "несоответствия тематике сайта" - взгляните на мои "довопросы" двухлетней давности. Сейчас подумаю, и напишу, на что/чему я от Вас недополучила разъяснений. )))

Comment: Вот первое, не так мною подуманное: "Из пещеры — вздох за вздохом, / Сотни вздохов, сонмы вздохов, / Фиолетовых на красном". Это цветаевский Лорка, и я полагала, что Б. А. обратилась именно к этому образу... Она, Б. А., "зла" только в одном: пребудут не живы - мне будет не жаль... Но ведь и впрямь - не жаль! Что она может изменить в этих уродах, не может она им "отпустить" - вот разве что в стихах явить их портреты: может, один из тысячи узнает себя, призадумается... А то сразу - голову на рельсы! Какая страшная, греховная тоска нам явлена!

Comment: А «колицем должен еси?» я восприняла ("перевела") как "скольким ты должна", не "сколько"...

Comment: Очень может быть, что Вы как раз перевели верно, потому что местоимённые слова прошли большую историю изменений, вполне может быть дательный падеж, по смыслу он больше подходит. Кстати, что, Ваш вопрос убрали? Я его не нашла в общем списке, только на Вашей странице. Видимо, никто не хочет его видеть. Вообще, Б.А. говорила: "Возможно, меня не поймут, но почувствуют точно". Вот Вы почувствовали. А я почувствовала, что такие люди, как Вы, ещё остались у нас - спасибо.

Comment: Я писала ответ поздно ночью, кое-что упустила, а заново перечитала -  там столько откровений, что ещё думать и думать. Ну вот, например, упустила, как рявкнул на неё селектор: "...ступай, ибо ты не должна ни нам, ни местам нашим гиблым и грубым. 
Таков уж твой сорт» = уходи, мол, если мы для тебя грязны, а потом она узнаёт, что один из рабочих покончил с собой, не выдержав этой серости, и понимает, что слишком себя возвысила, а их унизила - этим и задолжала. Гордыня-великий грех.

Comment: Люся, думайте исчо! Вид***е***ние расплющивания филигрань-человечка было ли упреждающей проекцией гибели сцепщика? Моя дочь Маня сказала, что Истец - это ангел-хранитель, а Селектор - голос гениуса лоци! Понятно, что гундосит про долги неправедный мытарь.

Comment: Ой, я ошиблась, ссылаясь на Маню. Истец - Бог, Суфлёр - ангел-хранитель, Селектор остаётся гением места, но, по Мане, это тёмная сила.

Comment: А почему "упреждающая проекция"?Она на самом деле видела силуэт сцепщика, бросившегося под поезд, но в темноте и красках заката, в том особом состоянии беседы с голосом небес  приняла за облако дыма. Шла и обвиняла рабочую окраину в мещанстве, восхищаясь праведником, потому ей и напомнили историю из Библии о неправедном мытаре, приносившем горе людям своими поборами, но искренне раскаявшемся, и фарисее, превозносившем свои заслуги и осуждавшем других людей.Бог простил грехи смиренному мытарю и осудил гордыню фарисея.

Comment: Отголоски Гениуса лоци, может, и есть(как покровителя окраины), я,правда, не увидела его, а почему он тёмная сила? Он правильно ей сказал: не имеешь права осуждать, не нравимся, считаешь злом - уходи. Она же почувствовала его правоту, что осталась должна  сцепщику. Я думаю, и Суфлёр, и Истец - один персонаж, Бог. С ним она говорила: "Если ты Тот, почему не избавишь рабочий посёлок от зла?" Селектор лишь изрёк его мысли. А потом пришёл к ней и сказал, что утро вечера мудренее, спи - и придут новые видения, новые мысли, что-то поймёшь. Потому она и уснула с молитвой, соединяющей с Богом.

Comment: Не-а, Суфлёр не = Бог. Смотрите: ***Суфлёр в занебесном укрытье шепнул:

«Ты знаешь его, он – неправедный мытарь.

Призвал он кого́ждо из должников,

и мало взыскал, и хвалим был от Бога».*** Если в прямой речи "хвалИм от Бога", то Суфлер явно отмежёвывается.

Comment: А может, весь диалог с Неправедным мытарем, он - Истец, требует долг, а Суфлёр, подсказчик,- Бог? Даёт знать, что он заодно с мытарем, что праведник не тот, кто не делает грехов, а тот, кто смиренно раскаялся? Посмела же она его поучать наставить на ум посёлок.

Comment: Если Истец = Неправедный мытарь, то от мытаря одно занудство, а мы знаем, что ***Истец улыбнулся: «Неправда, неправда»***. Мытарь при исполнении, он не улыбается.

Comment: Читала-читала об Ахмадулиной, нигде ничего об этом стихотворении, вот её идиостиль наталкивает на мысль, что она сама не разделяет этих персонажей, кроме мытаря, на которого указали. Так что есть мытарь, который взывает к её совести, напоминает о долге, он же истец, ведь с ним она ведёт диалог, он "незнаемый", ему она и говорит о неправедности округи, что ей не жаль их, если они умрут, значит, он и улыбнулся, потому что сам был такой, а Бог наставил на путь истинный, он теперь знает свой долг перед людьми и с неё требует. А Суфлёр - просто голос неба, необязательно Бог, ей это неважно.

Comment: То-то и оно-то, что нигде ничего. Мы с Вами первые! В ЖЖ что ль попробовать закинуть тему?..

Comment: Дорогая Галина! Отважусь оспорить Вашу трактовку слов   

  "Пребудут не живы – мне будет не жаль."    

Слова оные неотделимы от ответа Посылающего, содержащегося в следующей сроке:   

  "Истец улыбнулся: «Неправда, неправда»."    

Вкупе с рефреном "должна!" это наводит на параллели с историей библейского Ионы.