# "По причине в стране с бумагой напряжёнка" - здесь нарушено какое-либо правило? Какое?

Tags: согласование, управление, подчинительная-связь

Я очень часто употребляю подобные конструкции, никого не копируя, но отзвук помеси Веллера с Петрушевской признаю: оне мене спортили.

Фрагмент из "последовательности событий ночи 17 декабря 1916 года":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или:

> В делинквенты пошёл [восход малолетства](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432244/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%92%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%8E%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B0?noredirect=1#comment436849_432244) - по причине в стране с
> бумагой напряжёнка.

Требует душевного - какого? - типо а Ира (Ирина Александровна Юсупова) где;

по причине - какой? - в стране с бумагой напряжёнка.

Что тут не так? Согласование? Какое имя носит эта языковая проблема (если это проблема)?

Comment: :) Главное, что тут не так: у плавающего в теме автора нарушен порядок слов цитаты: "**с бумагой** в стране напряжёнка". Ещё Путина всегда неправильно цитируют: не произносил он никогда фразы "мочить в сортире", на самом деле сказал так: "... а зайдут в туалет - мы и в сортире их замочим!" Ну а про кавычки правильно уже сказали.

Comment: Это ж вольный пересказ цитаты, узнаваемой. На плагиат не тянет. Не, а почему автор плавает в теме? Он (я) не знает лингвистического термина, обзывающего феномен, об ём и спрашивает.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблему, на мой взгляд,  решают обычные кавычки. ***По причине "в стране с бумагой напряжёнка".*** - Несогласованное определение, выраженное устойчивым выражением-цитатой.

***Требует мадеры и душевного типа "а Ира где".*** - Несогласованное определение, выражено предложением.

Кавычки необходимы для выделения необычного определения, употреблённого в виде предложения.

Оба предложения усечённые, ср.: По причине, [выраженной фразой] "в стране с бумагой напряжёнка".Требует мадеры и душевного [высказывания]типа "а Ира где".

Используется *эллипсис* - намеренный пропуск слов, не существенных для смысла выражения.  Очень распространённое явление в устной речи и в текстах разговорного стиля.

Comment: "Ттипо" - это не опечатка, а современный жаргон, посталбанский язык, так сказать. Что-то вроде вводного слова со значением "примерно". Из-за этого ваша трактовка фразы сомнительна.

Answer (score 1):

**Р. кочевряжится: то буду, то не буду, требует мадеры и** (чего-нибудь) **душевного, типа** (= например) **"Ира где".**

1) Душевное ― это Ира,  здесь, как мне кажется,  оригинальная замена: вместо предмета ―  вопрос о нём.

2) Я бы обособила оборот, придав ему значение  уточнения.

3) Сленговое слово "типо" вместо "типа" здесь не очень к месту.

Comment: Сибичка, так это ж мой родной текст! Я так говорю! Всякая сниженная/сленговая лексика и "эллипсисы" (списано у Кати) иногда (а у меня - всегда)  работают на снижение градуса пафосности, иногда - призывают к: поиграйте со мной, что вы какие вусмерть правильныя! Вот выйдет из творческого отпуска моя мемуаристка - будем рисовать ВМПС им. Тургенева, вотъ.

Comment: Тогда — да, тогда, конечно, "типо" (а то правильная общественность в Сети выступает против). Ну и комплимент по оригинальной замене — тоже Ваш.

Comment: "Типа" это не "например". Это "напобобие". И в этом значении оно здесь к месту. Сам стиль не к месту, с этим бы согласилась.

Answer (score 0):

Я вопрос в целом не поняла, проблемы но в отношении Иры могу прояснить.

> Требует мадеры и душевного типо Ира где.

Тут можно по0оазному трактовать, но только не "душевного типа" - это совсем не оттуда.
1) *Р... требует мадеры и [чего-то] душевного наподобие "Ира где".*
При этом "Ира где" - это, типо, название такого душевного (специально построила фразу с демонстрацией семантики молодежного сленга). Такое понимание напрашивается на первый взгляд, но сомнительно по контексту.

2) *Р... требует мадеры и душевного, [произнося что-то типа] "Ира где"*
Вот это наиболее правдоподобно по некотором размышлении.

Я согласна, что кавычки решили бы проблему, но это явно не авторский стиль будет, проблемы решать.

По поводу вопроса в целом. Тут я большой проблемы не вижу. Это же не нацчная работа, автор имеет право на эрративы, грамматические не исключение.

2)